# How do (can) I use a custom.js file under Jupyter notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In the IPython notebook (v3.1, for example), I could add a `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js` file to execute some custom JavaScript.  For example, I could do something like this:

```
require(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
    console.log("A");
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
        console.log("B");
    });
    console.log("C");
});
```

Then, in the JS console, I would see `A`, followed by `B`, followed by `C`.

Now, as of version 4.0, they've split it out into the Jupyter notebook.  The same file gets loaded (despite the fact that it's under `~/.ipython`, rather than under `~/.jupyter`), and the code gets executed.  However, I no longer see the `B` line.  I guess the app isn't getting initialized.  I still see it get triggered in the [source code](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/309dab/notebook/static/notebook/js/main.js#L163), but does that comes later, or is it just not working?

How do I get things working again?  Do I just not need to wait for `app_initialized` any more?  Is any of this documented somewhere?

### Edit

[This page](http://akuederle.com/customize-ipython-keymap) seems to suggest that the way to do it nowadays is to create a custom extension and put all the action in the `load_ipython_extension` function.  Is that right?  If so, how about mathjax?  And CodeMirror options?

Answer (score 12):

Using `custom.js` still works for me, but it seems to move around a fair bit.

Currently (version `4.2.3`) as well as in the documentation for the upcoming `5.0` release, it's at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`. See the documentation at http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html#custom.js

You can show the path to and content of `custom.js` by executing this snippet in a notebook:

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_dir
jupyter_dir = jupyter_config_dir()
import os.path
custom_js_path = os.path.join(jupyter_dir, 'custom', 'custom.js')
print("searching for custom.js in ", custom_js_path)
#  my custom js
if os.path.isfile(custom_js_path):
    with open(custom_js_path) as f:
        print(f.read())
else:
    print("You don't have a custom.js file")
```

Answer (score 7):

> How do I get things working again? Do I just not need to wait for
>   app_initialized any more?

I don't have deep insight into the recommended way to do this, but with Jupyter/IPython 4.0, waiting on "notebook_loaded.Notebook" instead of "app_initialized.NotebookApp" works.  i.e. use this line:

```
    events.on("notebook_loaded.Notebook", function () {
```

Comment: > Is any of this documented somewhere? -- I don't know the answer, but maybe we can get @minrk to comment here.

Answer (score 5):

This question has arisen on the Github issue tracker - [Issues with jupyter 4.0](https://github.com/sjpfenninger/ipython-extensions/issues/2) - and links to a recent update that appears to simplify the loading of extensions: [code update](https://github.com/sjpfenninger/ipython-extensions/commit/6ad96d01b1c38f26e5d5115875cc2e1931e51e7c):

"By editing *notebook.json* manually. By default it is located at *~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json*:"

```
{
    "load_extensions": {
      "notify": true,
      "theme_toggle": true
  }
}
```

Adding things like `"code_folding/main": true` also seem to work.

So my understanding is that this would replace the use of `custom.js` for loading the extensions?

Answer (score 4):

The `app_initialized.NotebookApp` event is still fired if you look the notebook [`static/notebook/js/main.js`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4.0.x/notebook/static/notebook/js/main.js#L161) code.

but you have to listen at this event using the define() function from requireJS:

```
define([
  'base/js/namespace',
  'base/js/events'
], function(IPython, events) {
   events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
     // Your Code
   });
});
```

Here your callback will be executed.

If you put in your `custom.js` :

```
 require(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
     events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function() {
        console.log('require & notebook_loaded.Notebook');
    });
     events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
        console.log('require & app_initialized.NotebookApp');
     });
 });

 define(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
     events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function() {
        console.log('define & notebook_loaded.Notebook');
    });
     events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
         console.log('define & app_initialized.NotebookApp');
     });
 });
```

The result in the console will be :

```
define() & app_initialized.NotebookApp
define() & notebook_loaded.Notebook
require() & notebook_loaded.Notebook
```

I guess that with the `require()` you register to an event that had already happen...

`require()` is waiting for all dependencies and submodules to be intialized... which might be too late for the `app_initialized.NotebookApp` event.

Comment: do you still need to do this for jupyter 5.0+?