# IPython 3 to Jupyter migration, custom.js and events

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

in IPython3 my 'custom.js' was listening for the event :

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function() { ... })
```

After having a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170197/how-do-can-i-use-a-custom-js-file-under-jupyter-notebook/32974073#32974073), I'm listening for the 'notebook_loaded.Notebook' event.

```
require(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
  events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function() { ... });
});
```

But I was using 'app initialized' event to do some stuff including hiding the header, ie:

```
$('#header').hide()
```

And now, with this event, it's hiding, but just after a short display...
I think there is an event before notebook loaded, just like in IPython3 notebook

I didn't find any docs about those events..

Does it still have any event fired at the app initialization?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, you can't listen on the `app_initialized.NotebookApp` event when you use the require('base/js/events') function.

The `app_initialized.NotebookApp` event is still fired if you look the notebook [`static/notebook/js/main.js`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4.0.x/notebook/static/notebook/js/main.js#L161) code.

but you have to listen at this event using the define() function from requireJS:

```
define([
  'base/js/namespace',
  'base/js/events'
], function(IPython, events) {
   events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
     // Your Code
   });
});
```

Here your callback will be executed.

If you put in your `custom.js` :

```
 require(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
     events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function() {
        console.log('require & notebook_loaded.Notebook');
    });
     events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
        console.log('require & app_initialized.NotebookApp');
     });
 });

 define(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function(IPython, events) {
     events.on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function() {
        console.log('define & notebook_loaded.Notebook');
    });
     events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
         console.log('define & app_initialized.NotebookApp');
     });
 });
```

The result in the console will be :

```
define() & app_initialized.NotebookApp
define() & notebook_loaded.Notebook
require() & notebook_loaded.Notebook
```

I guess that with the `require()` you register to an event that had already happen...

`require()` is waiting for all dependencies and submodules to be intialized... which might be too late for the `app_initialized.NotebookApp` event.