# Shortcut / key combination to access Jupyter notebook menu bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I prefer the convenience and speed of the keyboard over using the trackpad/mouse whenever possible. Is there a means to access the `Jupyter` menu bar with the keyboard. For example the `Edit` menu:

[image]

On Linux we could access a top-level item as `Alt-E | D` for `Edit | Delete cells` .  On `macos` it is a headache but still possible:  `<Access Menubar shortcut>| E | D`.

Is there any way to achieve that on `Jupyter`?

Comment: As a workaround you can still bind each individual command in the "edit keyboard shortcut" menu.

Comment: True but I don't have the kind of memory (or interest) for four menus x N items per menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to bind custom keyboard shortcuts...

[The documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) tell you to use the JavaScript API, where the documentation is [in the source code](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html#Get-more-documentation).

So you end up with something like this in [`custom.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170197/5267751) (it's convenient that the first characters of all the menus are distinct)

```js
for(let id of ["filelink", "editlink", "viewlink", "insertlink", "celllink", "kernellink"]) {
    const element=document.getElementById(id)
    const actionName=Jupyter.notebook.keyboard_manager.actions.register(function (env) { element.click() },
        `open-menu-${id[0]}`, "custom")
    const shortcut='alt-'+id[0]
    Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut(shortcut, actionName)
    Jupyter.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut(shortcut, actionName)
}
```

This code binds <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to clicking edit menu.

It's rather version-dependent (as it depends on the ID of the links on the menu) -- this is tested on Jupyter notebook version 6.1.6.

If you use a for loop to generate the shortcuts (like in the code above), it's very important that you register actions manually (and have different names for them) instead of `add_shortcut(shortcut, handler)` because otherwise the handler would [generate the action name from the string representation of the handler](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/fb5deeed23479ff9a790a674993b00d39cc6b225/notebook/static/notebook/js/actions.js#L965), and that would be all the same. No [JavaScript closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5267751) can help you.

If you also want to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select a menu, you have to do a little more -- because by default it's bound to enter edit mode:

```js
{
    Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut("enter", function(env){
        const element=document.activeElement
        if(element.getAttribute("role")==="menuitem")
            element.click()
        else{
            env.notebook.edit_mode();
            // alternatively:
            //env.notebook.keyboard_manager.actions.call("jupyter-notebook:enter-edit-mode")
        }
    })
}
```

Modify it a little more if you want to add shortcut for the 2 other menus, as they don't conveniently have an ID.

Comment: As far as I know, jupyter doesn't support this natively so this is the best way; however it's possible to open an issue in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook).