# Jupyter notebook slideshow, how can the appearance of a new fragment trigger a property change on a previous fragment?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

Using Jupyter Notebook to prepare a slideshow,

I would like when a new fragment becomes visible, to trigger a property change (for example text color or font-size) on a previously shown fragment.

If it requires `addEventListener` could you provide a working example for a jupyter notebook?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found:

EDIT: [How do (can) I use a custom.js file under Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170197/how-do-can-i-use-a-custom-js-file-under-jupyter-notebook?rq=1)

Tag the target element and the trigger element with an `id`:

#### code:

```
<p id="target"> This text will become red and then green.</p>
<p class="fragment" id="trigger"> When this appears, the previous fragment will change color. When it disappears it will change color again</p>
```

#### screenshot:[image]

We need to add an event listener that listens to the `'fragmentshown'` event.
The eventlistener can not be in the Jupyter cell since cell contents are  loaded before Reveal is initialized.

Next convert to slides (for the notebook called test.ipynb):

`jupyter-nbconvert test.ipynb --to slides --post serve`

Next open the slides file `test.slides.html` with a text editor. At the bottom of the file we find the `require()` function that contains the Reveal initialization. Inside there (after the initialization) append the following commands:

#### code:

```
Reveal.addEventListener('fragmentshown', function( event ) {
        if(event.fragment.id === 'trigger') {  document.getElementById("target").style.color = "red";}
} );
Reveal.addEventListener('fragmenthidden', function( event ) {
        if(event.fragment.id === 'trigger') {  document.getElementById("target").style.color = "green";}
} );
```